# I'm a standard user even though i am the owner

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator

I'm sorry if this questions was asked before! When i wanted to delete a folder it gave me the error "You'll need to provide admin permission to delete this folder" and i was pretty confused cause i am the only owner.

So i went to Control Panel>add or remove acconts and I saw that there was my account, and and admin account called administrator that i made it by mistake and i can't delete it! i can't change my account type. what should i do??

Comment: What exactly is your question? You can't delete the default Administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that default administrator account is built in to Windows and is not deleteable.

Secondly, the reason you are asked to provide administrator permission is because you we're most likely attempting to delete a folder/file outside of your user folder, which you probably shouldn't be doing anyway.

You should just be able to click "confirm" and continue with the operation